# How can I generate native-debug-symbols file using java 11?

Tags: java, android

I can't generate native-debug-symbols file using Java 11. I changed Java version to 1.8 but get error because Gradle required version 11.
Help me, please. Thanks all.

This is my build.gradle (app level):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    publishNonDefault true
    compileSdkVersion 31
    ndkVersion "22.1.7171670"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.psoft.discoveryar"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 31
        multiDexEnabled = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
            }
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    version = "3.18.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: are you using Android Studio Artic Fox ?

Comment: Yes, I using Android Studio Artic Fox version 2020.3.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 0):

I think your Android Studio Artic Fox is creating this issue. replace this from your gradle

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

For Android Studio Artic Fox (2020.3.1) Android Gradle Plugin 7 requires Java 11. use short key **Ctr+Alt+Shift+S** or Go to **File > Project Structure** and change JDK location to Embedded JDK

[image]

I think this will help you. Let me know if your problem solved/

Comment: Thanks, but it's not work for me. When I using Java 1.8 in build.gradle file and Gradle JDK 11, I can't find native-debug-symbols file. When I using Java 1.8 in build.gradle file and Gradle JDK 1.8, I got an error "Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8"